# Relay: How to use emitted types when receiving error -> Type '"%future added value"' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, relay, react-relay

Current project for this question is using react, react-relay, and typescript. When trying to reuse a type emitted by Relay for an enum, an error occurs:

`Type '"%future added value"' is not assignable to type`

I did a little research and found that this is a backwards compatibility safeguard, which seems logical. There is also [a way to disable said future proofing](https://github.com/facebook/relay/commit/1e87e43add7667a494f7ff4cfa7f03f1ab8d81a2). I'd prefer not to remove that from this project, as my current issue is really about wanting to use an existing emitted type for an enum in a single page. Is there a way to keep backwards compatibility and still use Relay's emitted types?